# How to convert ListActivity to ListFragment?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listfragment, listactivity

i have a database which i created in Sqlite database browser and using a library to use that database for populating my lists in `ListActivity`. now to i want to convert my `ListActivity` to `ListFragment`...

here is the code...

code for `DataBaseHelper`

```
    import com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper;

    public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "dictionary.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

    }

    public Cursor getDictionary() {

        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

        String [] sqlSelect = {"0 _id", "dream_title", "dream_meaning"}; 
        String sqlTables = "dictionary";

        qb.setTables(sqlTables);
        Cursor c = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, null, null,
                null, null, null);

        c.moveToFirst();
        return c;

    }

}
```

code for `MainActivity`

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    private Cursor dictionary;
    private DataBaseHelper db;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        db = new DataBaseHelper(this);
        dictionary = db.getDictionary(); // you would not typically call this on the main thread

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
                dictionary, 
                new String[] {"dream_title"}, 
                new int[] {android.R.id.text1});

        getListView().setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        dictionary.close();
        db.close();
    }

}
```

Any help will be appreciable

Comment: I usualy use normal Fragment and use ListView and BaseAdapter

Comment: Do know how to use fragments?

Comment: i just have some basic knowledge... actually im a newbie in android platform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ListFragment uses `setListAdapter`. I think that's all you would need to change.

Comment: can you explain me a little more?

Comment: you use `getListView().setAdapter(adapter);`, but it will be `setListAdapter(adapter)` for a ListFragment